Frida - Unable to make thread_from_jni_environment() helper for the current architecture
I'm tried to replace the impl of $init method in the java.lang.String class, but when I load the script I get an error: "Error: Unable to make thread_from_jni_environment() helper for the current architecture"
System:

Ubuntu 23.10

Env:
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+7-Ubuntu-123.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+7-Ubuntu-123.10.1, mixed mode, sharing)

$ frida --version
16.2.1

Script:
console.log("java status:", Java.available) // True
Java.perform(() => {
    const groups = Java.enumerateMethods('*java.lang.String!*')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(groups, null, 2))
    groups[0]['classes'].forEach(element => {
        var obj = Java.use(element['name'])
        obj.$init.overload('java.lang.String').implementation = function (inp) {
            console.log(inp)
            return this.$init(arg1)
        }
    });
});

Output
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 16.2.1 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at https://frida.re/docs/home/
   . . . .
   . . . .   Connected to Local System (id=local)
Attaching...                                                            
java status: true
[
  {
    "loader": null,
    "classes": [
      {
        "name": "java.lang.String",
        "methods": [
          /* Methods */
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
Error: Unable to make thread_from_jni_environment() helper for the current architecture
    at Object.JavaThread::thread_from_jni_environment (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/jvm.js:191:1)
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/jvm.js:235:1
    at c.perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12:1)
    at R (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/jvm.js:234:1)


I've tried using different versions of Java:

11 (Error from header)
17 (Error from header)
19 (New error)
22 (New error)

With the last two I was getting a new error:
Error: Java API only partially available; please file a bug. Missing: _ZN6Method4sizeEb, _ZN6Method19set_native_functionEPhb, _ZN6Method21clear_native_functionEv, _ZN6Method10jmethod_idEv, _ZN20ClassLoaderDataGraph10classes_doEP12KlassClosure, _ZN8VMThread7executeEP12VM_Operation, _ZN11OopMapCache22flush_obsolete_entriesEv, _ZN14NMethodSweeper16sweep_code_cacheEv, _ZTV18VM_RedefineClasses, _ZN18VM_RedefineClasses4doitEv, _ZN18VM_RedefineClasses13doit_prologueEv, _ZN18VM_RedefineClasses13doit_epilogueEv, _ZNK18VM_RedefineClasses26allow_nested_vm_operationsEv, _ZN19Abstract_VM_Version19jre_release_versionEv, _ZN14NMethodSweeper11_traversalsE, _ZN14NMethodSweeper13_should_sweepE
    at E (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/jvm.js:146)
    at b (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/jvm.js:10)
    at _tryInitialize (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:29)
    at _ (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:21)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:332)
    at call (native)
    at o (/_java.js)
    at <anonymous> (/_java.js)
    at <anonymous> (frida/runtime/java.js:1)
    at call (native)
    at o (/_java.js)
    at r (/_java.js)
    at <eval> (frida/runtime/java.js:3)
    at _loadJava (native)
    at get (frida/runtime/core.js:134)



To my experience the support for J2SE of Frida is pretty poor or outdated. Not sure if it has been ever really adapted for Java 11 or 17. I assume this is because in next to 100% of all cases when Frida is used with Java, it is on Android and not on J2SE.

Solved.
Try AdaptiumOpenJdk 17

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
